# Change richselect's input color

Tags: javascript, html, css, select, webix

I wonder if it's possible to change the input's color in runtime.

Here's my select (Webix ui.richselect): http://webix.com/snippet/c64f9b12

```
{ 
  view:"richselect", label:"Status", options:[
    { id:1, value:"Done", $css:"done" },
    { id:2, value:"Processing", $css:"process" },
    { id:3, value:"On hold", $css:"on-hold" },
    { id:4, value:"Failed", $css:"failed" },
  ],
  on:{
    onChange:function(newV, oldV){           
      webix.message("Status changed to "+this.getList().getItem(newV).value)
    }
  }
}
```

Each `$css` key related to the CSS class that is applied to the item.

```
<style>
  .webix_list_item.done { 
    background:#ddf7dd; 
  }
  <!-- . . . -->
  .webix_list_item.webix_selected {
    color:black;
    font-weight:bold
  }
</style>
```

After changing the richselect's value, I need to set the background color of  the newly selected item as the background color of the richselect.

In my opinion, it can be done through the `onChange` event, but I have no idea how exactly I can solve it.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you explain "need to get the same color for the select's input after changing the value" - not very clear. which "select's input" are you talking about. where do you want the color change ?

Comment: Ok, sorry if I was not clear. Edited.

Comment: Hey, with view:combo I can help you but with view:richselect I am unable to get any success.

Comment: Ahh now its better .. Would you be willing to use JQuery ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Nikhil for the answer, it helped me to apply my combo logic on the richselect in the webix way.

So, the difference was that in the *combo* i was applying the style on the **input** and it was working but for the *richselect* applying the style on input was wrong rather i have to apply on the **.webix_inp_static** .

**1. CSS**

In your style **for each of your custom css on *webix_list_item* you have to also add css for *.webix_inp_static*** as shown:

```
<style>
  .done .webix_inp_static,.webix_list_item.done { 
    background:#ddf7dd; 
  }
</style>
```

**2. onChange function**

You have to [removeCss](http://docs.webix.com/api__html_removecss.html) on the oldV if existing and [addCss](http://docs.webix.com/api__html_addcss.html) on the newV as:

```
onChange:function(newV, oldV){ 
         if(oldV) webix.html.removeCss(this.getNode(), this.getList().getItem(oldV).$css);   
         if(newV) webix.html.addCss(this.getNode(), this.getList().getItem(newV).$css);            
        }
```

Please check the snippet [here](http://webix.com/snippet/b647d881).

Comment: This is exactly what I need, thank you and thanks to @NikhilNanjappa for the useful alternative!

Answer (score 2):

Here is your solution:

http://webix.com/snippet/08e187a7

1) First, dynamically get the class name of the element clicked in order to fetch that element

```
var className = ".webix_list_item." + this.getList().getItem(newV).$css;
var element = document.querySelector(className);
```

2) Next, just get the computed background color of that element and set the same to the "newly selected" element.

```
document.querySelector(".webix_el_richselect .webix_inp_static").style.backgroundColor = window.getComputedStyle(element,null).getPropertyValue("background-color");
```

I have written it one line, you could may be create variables and break it into more statements. say something like -

```
var clicked_bgcolor = window.getComputedStyle(element,null).getPropertyValue("background-color");

document.querySelector(".webix_el_richselect .webix_inp_static").style.backgroundColor = clicked_bgcolor;
```

I prefer doing these 2 in one line though(above mentioned).

**So your final `onChange` code would be**  :

```
  on:{
    onChange:function(newV, oldV){           
      webix.message("Status changed to "+this.getList().getItem(newV).value);

      var className = ".webix_list_item." + this.getList().getItem(newV).$css;
      var element = document.querySelector(className);
      document.querySelector(".webix_el_richselect .webix_inp_static").style.backgroundColor = window.getComputedStyle(element,null).getPropertyValue("background-color");
    }
  }
```

Let me know if any issues.

*PS: Try to use JQuery more often, you could avoid such lengthy complicated JavaScript statements.*

Comment: Got it! For now, I don't see any issues, thank you! But I will continue to look for a "webix way". Still curious if it's possible - there are so many things to learn.